# マクロ関数について

Tags: c

マクロ関数について勉強しています。

以下のコードを実行すると、エラーが出てしまいます。
解決法教えてください。

**エラーメッセージ**

```
error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment
 #define ABS(x)   x >= 0 ? x = x * 1 : x = x * -1;
                                         ^
.\5.c:9:5: note: in expansion of macro 'ABS'
     ABS(x);
     ^~~
```

**ソースコード**

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define ABS(x)   x >= 0 ? x = x * 1 : x = x * -1;

int main(){
    int x, y;
    scanf("%d %d", x, y);
    x += y;
    ABS(x);
    printf("%d\n", x);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

マクロ関数を使っていることはエラーとは直接関係ありません。マクロを使わずに書くと`ABS(x);`の部分は次のようになりますが、これでも同じエラーが出るはずです。

```
x >= 0 ? x = x * 1 : x = x * -1;
;
```

ここで三項演算子の優先順位は代入演算子のそれより高いので

```
(x >= 0 ? (x = x * 1) : x) = x * -1;
```

とカッコを付けたかのように解釈されます。`(x >= 0 ? (x = x * 1) : x)`は代入先として不適当なため、質問にあるようなエラーメッセージが表示されます。

直接的な修正としては、次のようにカッコをつけてやれば良いです。

```
x >= 0 ? (x = x * 1) : (x = x * -1);
```

参考: [C の演算子の優先順位 - cppreference.com](https://ja.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence)

あと今回の質問とは無関係ですが

- `scanf`の引数
- `ABS`マクロに余分なセミコロンがついている
- `ABS`という名を使うのであれば、絶対値を返すことだけに集中し、代入は外でやるべき

などいくつか気になる点があります。

Answer (score 4):

実はこの `ABS()` は [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) ではコンパイルに通ってしまいます。 [c](/questions/tagged/c) と [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) で仕様の違うところをピンポイントで踏み抜いているという。

[c](/questions/tagged/c) において演算子の結合規則（コンパイラが見るとき、どっちを先に処理するか）は
https://ja.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence
これによると三項演算子 `? :` は代入より先に解釈されるので当該 `ABS(x);` は

```
(x >= 0 ? x = x * 1 : x) = x * -1;;
```

と解釈されます。代入演算子の左辺が変数でないので怒られています。

[c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) では https://ja.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence の注２から

```
x >= 0 ? (x = x * 1) : x = x * -1;;
```

となるのでコンパイルでき、期待通りに動きます。

で、この質問の回答からずれるので詳細は省略しますが、出来る限り `#define` マクロは避けてください。この簡単そうな `ABS()` マクロですが、実用的に使おうとすると複数個の問題を抱えています。どれだけ問題（になりそうな）点があるかを読者の皆様も数えてみてください。最低３個は指摘できるはず。

---

どう修正すればよいかは、オイラ的には `#define` を使わないでください、になりそうです。ほかの方の回答も「実用レベルで安全に使う」には不合格です（ QAC や PgRelief 等分析ツールがビシバシ指摘してきます）。

Comment: 引数が複数回評価されるので、単項演算で意図しない結果になる、演算式を書くとコンパイルエラーになるかも知れない。でも書き方によっては、これは回避できそう。けっこう難しいです。関数で表現できるときは引数付きdefineマクロを使わないので今まであまり考えていませんでした。

Answer (score 0):

- 勉強中とのことですので直接の回答ではありませんが、三項演算`(condition ? expr1 : expr2)`に書けるのは式です。代入文を書きたいならば`if`文にしましょう。※ 訂正です。代入も式でした。他の人の回答でわかりました。
- 引数付きのマクロは関数に似ているので、ABS(x)でxの値が書き換わるのは違和感があります。
  マクロは値を表現するようにして、利用するときに代入した方がよいです。

```
x = ABC(x);
```

コンパイルしてみたら致命的な警告メッセージも出ていました。※q3.cはソースファイル名です

```
q3.c:8:17: warning: format specifies type 'int *' but the argument has type 'int' [-Wformat]
        scanf("%d %d", x, y);
               ~~      ^
q3.c:8:20: warning: format specifies type 'int *' but the argument has type 'int' [-Wformat]
        scanf("%d %d", x, y);
                  ~~      ^
```